# In Makefile, how can I make a target with appended name from each members of list?

Tags: makefile

I want to make a Makefile so that if I type `make q_a` it runs `qemu aarch64/a/a.elf`, and if I type `make q_b` then it runs `qemu aarch64/b/b.elf`.
How can I do that with Makefile?  (you can assume I have a limited list for a, b, c,..  but I would be happier if there is no limitation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
q_%: ; echo $*
```

Read about [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) and [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

After you clarified your question, you can use this:

```
q_% : ; qemu aarch64/$*/$*.elf
```

Comment: that was so simple. thank you. the actual problem was to run `qemu aarch64/a/a.elf` for `make q_a` and `qemu aarch64/b/b.elf` for `make q_b`. Now with q_% : ; qemu aarch64/%/%.elf` it works ok. (I had tried similar rule but had a wrong dependency before).

Comment: You cannot use `%` multiple times in a prerequisite.  It won't work.  Your real problem is so much different, and so much more complicated, than the question you asked here that this answer won't help you much.

Comment: Ah yes correct. the %/% doesn't work in the recipe.. Isn't there any method of doing this? Thanks anyway for helping me.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. That's much better.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and it works.
(actual command is more complex, but I reduced it to match my question)

```
q_% :
    qemu aarch64/$(subst q_,,$@)/$(subst q_,,$@).elf
```

Comment: You don't need `$(subst q_,,$@)`.  You can just use `$*`, as I said in my answer above.  The problem was not using the file in the recipe.  The problem was using multiple patterns in a prerequisite.